# Ruby: postgresql create db error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

When I ran `rake db:create` in my terminal
I got the following error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `connect'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"SmartConnect_development", "host"=>"localhost", "port"=>5432}
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `connect'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"SmartConnect_test", "host"=>"localhost", "port"=>5432}
```

My database.yml looks like this:

```
test:
  <<: *default
  database: SC_test
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
development:
  <<: *default
  database: SC_development
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

I have edited my postgresql conf file to accept all connections (host = '*') and changed my IPv4 to accept 0.0.0.0/0. However, this error persists. Any pointers to why?

Comment: Have you already run the postgres database?

Comment: are you able to connect to postgres console by typing this psql or psql -U postgres

Comment: Most likely this has nothing to do with your Rails app or your Rails database.yml. You just need to start a Postgres server on your local machine. On my Mac, I do this by launching [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to having Postgres installed, you'll need to make sure it's running before ruby can use it.

You can easily configure postgres to run automatically at startup, so you don't have to do this every time:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents

ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents

launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

[This link](http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/21/install-postgresql-on-mac-os-x-via-brew/) has more info.